# SQL Server (MsSQL) Concat error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below code executing perfectly fine in Sybase database but same query is giving error in MsSQL server.

```
select
  column1,
  (
    Case when  ABC < 0 then CONVERT(varchar(50), Convert(int,PQR)) + "/" + CONVERT(varchar(50), Convert(int,ABC)) 
        else CONVERT(varchar(50), Convert(int,PQR)) 
    end
  )  as column2, 
  column3,
  column4
FROM SAMPLE_TABLE
```

Error is : **Invalid column name '/'.**

Comment: Put the slash in single quotes.

Answer (score 3):

In MSSQL (and apparently is the standard - see comments), strings are encapsulated in single quotes, like this... `'here is a string'`.

You double them up to escape them... `'here''s another string that includes a single quote'`

Double quotes refer to objects.  It's not commonly used, at least in my experience.  I much prefer square brackets, but they are equivalent.  For example, these two are exactly the same thing...

```
SELECT
    "Some Field"
FROM
    YourTable
```

and

```
SELECT
    [Some Field]
FROM
    YourTable
```

So, in your code, `"/"` is looking for a field called fowardslash.  Simple correction...

```
select
  column1,
  (
    Case when  ABC < 0 then CONVERT(varchar(50), Convert(int,PQR)) + '/' + CONVERT(varchar(50), Convert(int,ABC)) 
        else CONVERT(varchar(50), Convert(int,PQR)) 
    end
  )  as column2, 
  column3,
  column4
FROM SAMPLE_TABLE
```

Comment: This isn't actually SQL Server specific, this is how string literals are defined in the SQL standard.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for the clarification.  I never remember what is MSSQL specific and what deviates from the standard.  I just know what works in MSSQL, and cringe every time I see a query with a backtick in it!

Comment: Well, I always cringe when I see a query with square brackets ;) (non-standard as well)